# UK regions is incomplete in Ordnance Survey BoundaryLine data

Tags: data, united-kingdom, ordnance-survey

This question is about United Kingdom Ordnance Survey(OS) open Mapsets.

I have downloaded bdline_essh_gb from OS Open maps. But I don't see the boundaries for all the regions there - I am only interested in English regions currently. The one missing mainly are Midlands regions.

Does anyone else has the same problem?

Comment: I think that this question would be better researched/asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

In England we have potentially three types of local government - either a local council + county council or a unitary authority (i.e. a combination of the two). This leads to gaps in the county coverage:

[image]

If you simply require a coverage of the whole of GB then you probably want to use the ceremonial counties layer, which contains Scotland and Wales too:

[image]

Alternatively if you are using the boundaries for a statistical map you can create regions from district/borough/unitary authorities, or build up from [super output areas](http://neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk/HTMLDocs/nessgeography/superoutputareasexplained/output-areas-explained.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I have an recent copy of OS Open Borderline and see that not all layers have full coverage (especially in England). I think it really depends on the definition of 'region' you want :)

I don't think it's necessarily a problem with the data, it's more the result of having multiple types of 'region' with different meanings.

If you're looking at some of the Unitary Authority layers, that might explain the gaps in coverage - not all of England is covered by [Unitary Authorities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_authorities_of_England) (e.g. gaps in the Midlands, Somerset, Isle of Wight etc). The same goes for the "county regions" layer which has similar gaps.

Not too familiar with the intricacies of geopolitical boundaries in England, I'm afraid. [This wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_government_in_England) looks as if it might explain the gaps you're seeing.

For other sources, ask on OpenData stackenchange as others have suggested.